# Making the ios app in app store so that one apple id can install the app once

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store

Although it does not look like a technical question however it is, cause I want to make my app in the way that one apple id can download the app once and if he/she wants to re-download or re-install it, it will be prohibited from the app store or from the app itself in the device(Programatically).

The reason behind the same is to make one registration per apple id in the app so that I can choose the identical one from many.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Even if possible it would be against Apple's rules -- they insist that users can install each app on all of a users devices.

Comment: Thanks @stephen.....with the same apple id I assume.??

Comment: Yes, but Apple tend to assume you only have one account.

Answer (score 1):

**Only one download for each Apple Id**

> That's against Apple's software philosophy is that once you downloaded it, you can use, delete, redownload it.

**An Idea**

> Add a non-consumable in-app purchase to your app. for registration. you can set this purchase to be free. That will grantee that an apple id will only register once. seems to be a good idea.

In the iTunes connect you can add in-app purchases to your app. (people will purchase from inside your app.) there are 3 types of purchases (products). A non-consumable product is only allowed to be purchased once per apple id. You also can set this purchase to be free.

```
You need to include the store kit in your project to handle store management.
```

Every time a user try to register will enter his/her apple id to purchase a registration. (you can call it registration key as a store name). apple store will send your app a receipt which you will validate to let the user register or you just tell him you already have an account with the following username and password. or you can let him reset his password.

Comment: Could you please elaborate the third point?

Comment: You mean the in-app purchase?

Comment: @hasan as of iOS7 there is no way to identify device any more, the mac address returned on every device will be the same. Also you should never ever identify a device. [You should identify a user](http://triplesoftware.nl/2012/03/uniqueidentifier-deprecated-is-a-good-thing/).

Comment: That's true that don't work for iOS7 I will include that in answer.

Comment: What do you think about the in-app purchase idea?

Comment: @hasan yes the in-app purchase one. Could you please elaborate it more?

Comment: I will edit and I will keep the in-app purchase idea. and I will add more details please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible to do with the valid API's you are allowed to use for the store. You'd need to be jailbroken.

You can keep a record of the device on your own server and restrict functionality that way.

Comment: Thanks @John Woods, okay then is it possible to track the user's apple id from the download of the app?

Comment: @Saty no, you will not be able to get the Apple ID of the user, this is against the privacy terms of Apple.  Also it is against the App Store guidelines to restrict the number of installs. You are allowed to install the app on 5 device using the same Apple ID.

Comment: @Saty you can get a UDID for the devices running your app and restrict access by vetting the UDIDs against your own database.

Comment: So, if I understood you correctly there is no chance of getting the user identity or restricting the user from install twice or more unless he/she use the same user name to register with my app. UDID is also prohibited now, I suppose?

Comment: @JohnWoods...You should not use UDID from the device, its apple's new UX Guidelines, I presume?

Comment: @JohnWoods you can no longer get the UDID in iOS 7, nor can you get the any unique device identifier. Even the MAC address is not available in iOS 7. Also [you should identify a user not his device.](http://triplesoftware.nl/2012/03/uniqueidentifier-deprecated-is-a-good-thing/)

Comment: @rckoenes, I know, but you can get and store UUID to identify a device.

Comment: @JohnWoods UUID or UUID....is it typo error?

Comment: @JohnWoods depending on where you store the create `UUID` it will not persist. If you place the `UUID` in the keychain a user how will reset there device can again reinstall the app. What Saty is trying to do is just never going to be full prove and as Stephen Darlington said against Apple guidelines. Also you are identifying device, but you want to identify the user, never the device.